# How to loop array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table, from this table I want to select all, where array(). My array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    ..etc..
)
```

I use this:

```
$db->where('id',array(***,***),"IN");
$db->get('cars');
```

How can I loop the array to be correct? Like this for example:

```
$db->where('id',array($this->car[0],$this->car[1]),"IN");
```

I tried to put "`array(*here*)`" while or for to loop but its not working.

Comment: Where you're using `array($this->car[0],$this->car[1])`, can you just use `$this->car`? I assume that this class property is a regular array rather than an iterable class.

Comment: $db->where('id',array($this->cars),"IN");

If u think this its not working!

Comment: No, not `array($this->cars)` - use `$this->cars` instead, as it is already an array. Of course, this depends on the format expected by your `$db` class, which could be anything, but my guess would be that this should be an ordinary array to get an `IN` where clause.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, this should be:

`$db->where('id',$search->cars,"IN");`

Comment: Great! Does `where()` do parameter binding for you in your database class? Make sure it is proofed against SQL injection.